# Implementing Cochran's theorem using ChiSquareDistribution[ν]

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

When samples of $n$ observations are taken from the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then Cochran's theorem states that $\frac{n S^2}{\sigma^2} \backsim \chi^2_{n-1}$. Clearly, this distribution is a function of the population variance.

I am having difficulty working out exactly how I can express the distribution of $S^2$ using Mathematica's `ChiSquareDistribution[ν]`, which has a single parameter $\nu$ capturing degrees of freedom.

To express the distribution of $S^2$ using Mathematica's `ChiSquareDistribution[ν]`, do I simply multiply `ChiSquareDistribution[ν]` by $\sigma^2$ and divide by $n$?

Perhaps someone can confirm/dis-confirm my approach, ideally by stating the exact expression of how to solve the stated problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To obtain the distribution with *Mathematica* functions one sees that $S^2$ is a multiple of a $\chi^2$ random variable with $n-1$ degrees of freedom:  $S^2=(\sigma^2/n)\chi^2_{n-1}$.

```
distS2 = TransformedDistribution[σ^2 x2/n, 
  x2 \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[n - 1]]
(* GammaDistribution[1/2 (-1+n),(2 σ^2)/n] *)
```

The expectation of $S^2$ is found with

```
Expectation[s2, s2 \[Distributed] distS2]
(* ((-1+n) σ^2)/n *)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, the probability distribution `pdf` and the cummulative probability distribution `cdf` of $S^2$ should be given by

```
pdf = n/σ^2 PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n - 1]][t n/σ^2];
cdf = CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n - 1]][t n/σ^2];
```

Some wuick consistency tests for the scalings:

```
Integrate[pdf, {t, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {σ > 0, n >= 2}] == 1
Limit[cdf, t -> ∞, Assumptions -> {σ > 0, n >= 2}] == 1
D[cdf, t] == pdf // Simplify
```

> True
>
> True
>
> True

Comment: I think you meant to have $n/\sigma^2$ rather than $\sigma^2/n$:  `pdf = (n/σ^2) PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n - 1]][t n/σ^2];`.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the hint! I am not able to figure it out (transformation formula is soo puzzling, you know), so I am relying on your expertise here. =D